# Linq to Sql design and MVP

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, mvp

I'm experimenting with LinqToSql and the MVP pattern and having trouble setting on a good design. I'm using Asp.net 3.5 (not MVC)

Here is a example

```
public interface IMyBusinessCardView
{
    string Field1 { get; set; }
    string Field2 { get; set; }
    string Field15 { get; set; }
}

public class MyBusinessCardPresenter
{
    private IMyBusinessCardView _view;
    private MyBusinessCard _myCard;

    public void ViewClickedSave()
    {
        _myCard.SaveNewBusinessCard(_view);
    }

    public void LoadView()
    {
        _myCard.LoadMyBusinessCardToView(_view);
    }
}

public class MyBusinessCard
{
    public void SaveNewBusinessCard(IMyBusinessCardView view)
    {
        using (var context = new DataContext())
        {
            var card = new BusinessCard()
            {
                Field1 = view.Field1
            };
            context.BusinessCards.InsertOnSubmit(card);
            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }

    public void LoadMyBusinessCardToView(IMyBusinessCardView view)
    {
        // Query using Linq to Sql and set in view
        view.Field1 = card.Fields1;
    }
}
```

I'm thinking
The view and controller are very thin, that's good I guess.
The "model" has access to the view, is that bad?
Should I introduce DTO objects or should I use the LinqToSql generated entities.

Please provide feedback to the design.

Answer (score 2):

In MVP, the bulk of the work should be in the presenter; the less the view knows about the presenter, the better.  I haven't seen anything where the model works with the view; I've seen where the presenter does all of the coordination.  With a single page, there could be multiple presenters to spread around the logic.

Check out the images in this for two types of MVP patterns (passive view and supervising controller): http://www.yeejie.com/blog/post/2009/01/19/MVP-Passive-View-Supervising-Controller-Presentation-Model.aspx

In this example, even though the view access the model in supervising controller, it doesn't actually operate on the view.

EDIT: just came across this framework: http://webformsmvp.codeplex.com/ as an implementation.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

While I believe that it makes more sense to not link the View and the Model, let's not forget that MVP design pattern has two different "flavors": the so-called Passive View and the so-called Supervising Controller. Read up on this at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647543.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out this project on codeplex for some inspiration
http://www.codeplex.com/NSK

I'd also recommend reading the related book - it's an excellent read.
http://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-NET-Architecting-Applications-PRO-Developer/dp/073562609X

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not a good idea to tie knowledge of the view (or presenter) into the model.

If you use Linq-to-sql objects as model classes, then your view will end up with intimate knowledge of the data layer.

If the above two statements are acceptable, then that pretty much leaves DTO's as the answer.

Also, I've had good results from defining event properties on the Presenter, instead of a view interface.
Makes it easier to unit-test specific cases, by just attaching to the relevant events.

Comment: >>Definitely not a good idea to tie knowledge of the view (or presenter) into the model.   -------- Just to understand you, are you saying that I do that in my example or you talking in general terms?

Comment: @Karsten - in general; the model's responsibility is to represent the data

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my opinion MVP pattern with passive view, more common one;

- View includes just UI related stuff
- Model is not aware of view at all, and model just takes care of data access codes.
- Presenter is the most important one, keeps all the business logic of the application.

  the idea of of separating business logic into presenter is to enable unit testing directly over the part of code which produce most critical bugs. So your simple code would look like this.

  ```
  public class MyBusinessCardPresenter
      {
          private IMyBusinessCardView _view;
          private MyBusinessCard _myCard;

          public void ViewClickedSave()
          {
              //You can have all your business logic here which is easy to test
              var businessCard = new BusinessCard()
              {
                  Field1 = _view.Field1
              };

              _myCard.SaveNewBusinessCard(businessCard);
          }

          public void LoadView()
          {
              _view.Field1 = _myCard.LoadMyBusinessCardToView().Field1;
          }
      }

      public class MyBusinessCard
      {
          public void SaveNewBusinessCard(BusinessCard businessCard)
          {
              using (var context = new DataContext())
              {
                  context.BusinessCards.InsertOnSubmit(businessCard);
                  context.SubmitChanges();
              }
          }

          public BusinessCard LoadMyBusinessCardToView()
          {
              // Query using Linq to Sql and set in view
              return card;
          }
      }
  ```